Debian gave up waiting for root file system device
My computer gets stuck booting on initramfs. It says something about an unknown UUID for root.
I'm not sure what to do with this as using the shell on a live usb it looks like the correct UUID for my Debian partition.

Please include the output of cat /proc/partitions at the (initramfs) prompt into your question. Also describe what you changed on the system before encountering this problem.
